# Soma de valores em variavel nao ocorre, tofixed

Tags: javascript

Era para ele ir somando.. mas nao aconteceu, adicionei o `parsefloat` por que estava dando error de que nao era uma funçao..

```
var x = 0;
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4)).toFixed(1); // 0.4
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4)).toFixed(1); // 0.8
alert(x); // 0.8
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4)).toFixed(1); // 1.2
alert(x); // 1.2
```

deveria ser como nos comentarios mas.. qual é o problema? o ToFixed ta fazendo algo errado? Ele retorna sempre 0.4

http://jsfiddle.net/rtmobcz5/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema é que você está concatenando strings, (retorno do `toFixed`) e não somando numeros:

```
var x = 0;
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4)).toFixed(1); // "0.4"    <-saída verdadeira
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4)); // "0.40.4" que depois de parseFloat e toFixed vira "0.4" novamente
```

A primeira "soma" dá "0.40.4", e o parsefloat pega até onde entende (o primeiro "0.40").

Uma solução seria essa:

```js
var x = 0;
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4).toFixed(1) ); // 0.4
document.body.innerHTML += x + '<br>';
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4).toFixed(1) ); // 0.8
document.body.innerHTML += x + '<br>';
x = parseFloat((x + 0.4).toFixed(1) ); // 1.2
document.body.innerHTML += x + '<br>';
```

Notas:

- O "tofixed" neste caso poderia ser aplicado em outra ordem, por exemplo na hora de mostrar na tela apenas. só mantive no código para você poder comparar com o original.
- troquei o `alert` pelo `innerHTML` apenas para facilitar a leitura aqui na página.

Simplificando mais ainda:

```js
var x = 0;
x += 0.4 // 0.4
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(1) + '<br>';
x += 0.4 // 0.8
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(1) + '<br>';
x += 0.4 // 1.2
document.body.innerHTML += x.toFixed(1) + '<br>';
```

Aqui simplesmente tiramos o parseFloat, pois o toFixed foi usado só na hora de exibir na tela, sem atrapalhar as somas.

Comment: qual a funçao do parsefloat nisso tudo entao, só fazer virar string?

Comment: nao, o parsefloat é justo o inverso. o problema foi o .tofixed fora dos ( ). O parseFloat, do jeito que eu fiz, faz com que o toFixed volte a ser numero. Do jeito que você fez, ele virava numero, mas em seguida o .toFixed fazia virar string de novo; Ou seja, o parsefloat tem que ser aplicado depois do tofixed para poder somar, e nao antes.

Comment: @user3163662 complementei a resposta com mais um exemplo, veja se ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que esses numeros estão em formato *string* e não *number*.

O que esses métodos retornam:

- [parseFloat(string)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Aceita uma string e converter para numero sem arredondar. O método parecido que arredonda para inteiros é o [`parseInt(string, base);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Retorna no formato *number*.

- [toFixed(casasDecimais)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed)

Aceita um numero com casas decimais (parte fracional). Retorna uma *string*.

#### Sugestão:

Sugiro criar uma função que faça isso, e que pode dar conta de casos diferentes:

```
function soma(a, b, casasDecimais) {
    if (typeof a == 'string') a = parseFloat(a);
    if (typeof b == 'string') b = parseFloat(b);
    var soma = a + b;
    return soma.toFixed(casasDecimais);
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/07j4t8ag/